# What's the difference between char and CHAR in MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++

I heard that these 2 types (char and CHAR) are different in MSVC, what's the difference between them? And which one is recommended to use if they are different?

Comment: I use CHAR when I'm really angry and want the code to just work.  Normally I use char, though, as I don't often get so angry that I turn on CAPS LOCK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no actual difference.  `CHAR` is a typedef to `char`, and its part of the Windows API not technically MSVC.  See [Windows Datatypes at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

All of the (well most all) Windows API functions use parameters types that are defined in in the Win32 API header files than direct C types.  I've always assumed that this was to be able to support multiple compilers (MSVC hasn't always been the dominant C compiler for Windows)

Comment: Do you mean `CHAR` is an intention to support multiple compilers? But other compilers maybe doesn't define `CHAR` as `char` in typedef, so how can it do so?

Comment: CHAR is typedef'd in a Windows API header file, not in a compiler at all.  CHAR is defined WinNT.h as is listed at the link in my question.